# How to write a validation method for derived classes object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm reading user input from different types of CSV files having a few common and a few different attributes. I have created a base class TestCaseData and derived classes as below:

```
public abstract class TestCaseData
{
 public abstract string ID { get; set; }
 public abstract string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClassOne :TestCaseData
{
public override string ID { get; set; }
public override string Name{ get; set; }

pubic string DerivedOneProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClassTwo :TestCaseData
{
public override string ID { get; set; }
public override string Name{ get; set; }

pubic string DerivedTwoProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

I am reading the CSV file and creating a list of derived classes and assigning to list of base class as below

```
List<TestCaseData> lstTestCaseData = MethodCallToReturnListOf_DerivedOneClassFromCSV();
```

As now I have `lstTestCaseData` I have to validate the user inputs also where I am unable to find a way to write a single method to validate user input of type `DerivedOneProperty` or `DerivedTwoProperty` as they have their own properties. Anyone can help me here?

I have method signature something like that

```
 public string ValidateCompleteFile(List<TestCaseData> TestCaseInputList, out bool IsInputValid)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead put an abstract validation method on the TestCaseData class and then let each class that inherits this class implement it how they need to.

```
public abstract class TestCaseData
{
 public abstract string ID { get; set; }
 public abstract string Name{ get; set; }
 public abstract bool Validate();
}
```

And then call this method for each entry in the TestCaseInputList collection.

Comment: Seems quite reasonable, although I'd probably prefer encapsulating the validation in the class constructor (although sometimes this is not possible because of 3rd party libs doing the parsing). I think it's a lot more clean to be able to assume that every created object is valid instead of giving clients responsibility for calling `IsValid()` all over the place.

Comment: I agree that this isn't the optimal solution but since the question talked about the existing ValidateCompleteFile method, this new Validate method would just be called from here.

Comment: Actually the problem is I am a writing a client code using Models TestCaseData, DerivedClassOne ,DerivedClassTwo and can not modify class definition (which doesn't offer Validate method). So now it's required in client code to write a separate method for validation and I don't want to write two different validate method one for type DerivedClassOne and other for Type DerivedClassTwo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding an abstract method is the best solution if you're committed to the code pattern you originally conceived of (i.e. calling a validation method on each object). But perhaps it would be better to validate each field in its setter:

```
public abstract class TestCaseData
{
    private string id, name;

    public abstract string ID { get; set; }
    public abstract string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClassOne : TestCaseData
{
    public override string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if ( ... ) throw new ArgumentException();

            ...

            id = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

This way an exception is thrown as soon as an invalid value is encountered. Imagine if you created a million of these objects before checking if each one was valid, only to find that the very first one was invalid. This solution avoids a situation like that by proactively validating as the properties are set.

Comment: Only keep in mind that this can be misleading if `null`/`default(T)` isn't an acceptable value for every property! I agree that setter validation (although I prefer construction injection/setter methods over properties) is a good thing, but if it doesn't cover all invariants it can cause a false sense of security.